# How to implement bash's vertical bar operator in python console?

Tags: python, bash, console

I wish i could write like

```
>>> print many_lines_message | tail -1
```

in python console, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to pass the output of an arbitrary Python expression to an external command, you will need to start a process and use a pipe. In bash a pipe is spelt `|`, in Python the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module can help you with that. But if you just need the example you gave, the answers by eumiro and Jon Clements are what you need.

Answer (score 9):

```
print many_lines_message.splitlines()[-1]
```

If you want to simulate `head`, `tail` and/or `grep` commands, it is easy with slices and/or list comprehensions.

If you want to do something different, give us more examples.

Answer (score 2):

I was fiddling with @eumiro's solution because I supposed it could be too slow and tail can be way more efficient. Actually, it is much slower but still not in a significant way. While `tail -1` consumes this time:

```
$ seq 1 10000000 > f
$ time tail -1 f
10000000

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

The Python version consume as much as 200 times more time:

```
>>> #message = "\n".join(str(i) for i in range(0, 10000000))
>>> %timeit message.splitlines()[-1]
1 loops, best of 3: 679 ms per loop
```

Of course, this is not that relevant: you will not even see how much time it took because half a second is almost imperceptible. Summing up, eumiro's solution is *the* solution.

However, it can become too slow for some files, such as big logs, so a quicker Python solution can be helpful:

```
>>> %timeit message.rsplit('\n', 1)[-1]
10 loops, best of 3: 50.7 ms per loop
```

In this case, i use [`rsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit), which will split the string at each `'\n'` char from the end to the beginning exactly one time. That is, it will split the string into two strings, one containing all the message except the last line, and the last line itself. Then, I get the last line with the `-1` index.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the last element(s) of an iterable is using a `deque`:

```
from collections import deque
last_item = deque(your_message, maxsize=1)[0]
```

Comment: The `deque` constructor did not accept the keyword `maxsize` in my machine (either Python 2.7 and Python 3.2). Is it correct?